# Not able to nack messages in RabbitMQ using SprintBoot

Tags: java, spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-rabbit

I have the following `Consumer` class that listens to incoming messages on a queue and then both acks and nacks them. The `ack` part is working fine but the `nack` is not working. All the messages gets acked for some reason.

**application.properties**

```
spring.rabbitmq.host=192.168.99.100
spring.rabbitmq.port=5677
spring.rabbitmq.username=abc
spring.rabbitmq.password=def
spring.rabbitmq.listener.acknowledge-mode=manual
```

**Producer.java**

```
@Component
public class Producer implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    private RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate;

    @Autowired
    private Queue queue;

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            this.rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend(this.queue.getName(), "Hello World !");
        }
    }

}
```

**Consumer.java**

```
@Component
public class Consumer {

    private final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
    int ctr = 0;

    @RabbitListener(queues = "producer-consumer-nack2.q")
    public void receiveQueue(String text, Channel channel, @Header(AmqpHeaders.DELIVERY_TAG) long tag) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        ctr++;
        //nack every 10th, 20th, 30th and so on message 
        if (ctr % 10 == 0) {
            System.out.println("Nack Message #" + ctr + ": " + text);
            channel.basicNack(tag, false, true);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Ack Message #" + ctr + ": " + text);
            channel.basicAck(tag, true);
        }
        latch.countDown();
    }

    public CountDownLatch getLatch() {
        return latch;
    }

}
```

Since all the messages got consumed the queue is empty (see below).
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the way nack works is that it will reject then queue the message for redelivery at the same point in the queue. (See rabbitmq documentation [here](https://www.rabbitmq.com/nack.html))

Therefore, as you are looking at the end of processing it will have been rejected and then reprocessed later on.

I'd suggest debugging the code, with a breakpoint in your nack condition (or a print) to see if it hits that code block. Then if you debug till right after the nack but before the next processing of a message and check your queue - I think you'll see a nacked message.